# Access error when creating domain Storage Buckets via Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When I try to create storagebuckets via Deployment Manager I get the error message below. I have already tried adding `1058303916595@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` to the list of Verified owners of that domain on the Google Search Console but still no luck.

```
message: '{"ResourceType":"storage.v1.bucket","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"The
bucket you tried to create requires domain ownership verification.","reason":"forbidden"}],"message":"The
bucket you tried to create requires domain ownership verification.","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b","httpMethod":"POST","suggestion":"Consider
granting permissions to 1058303916595@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"}}'
```

I am trying to deploy from inside a `google/cloud-sdk` imaged container. I am logged-in via my gmail account which is a Project Owner.

Comment: are you still having this issue?